# Why cant i save an array of struct into coredata?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to save an array of structs into coredata.

```
class Model: NSManagedObject
{

 @NSManaged var decks:[astruct]  //Error here
}
```

and the struct

```
struct astruct
{
let card:Card
var status:Bool
}


enum Card:Int
{
    ..
}
```

Error states: property cant be marked @NSMAnaged because its type cant be represented in obj-c

Comment: Like this var decks:[astruct]!

Comment: and delete '@NSManaged'

Answer (score 0):

CoreData at a high level is just a wrapper around a lightweight relational database.  As with all relational databases, you're limited with what data types can be stored.  From the xcdatamodeld file you can select it in Xcode, here is an example entity with an example attribute with the supported types:

[image: CoreData entity attribute data types]

In the screenshot you can see, as with other relational databases, there is no array data type in CoreData.  You should work with CoreData as you would other relational databases.  If you have complex data structures in your application that you need to store/retrieve then you need to plan how to break down and convert your application data structures into compatible relational database entities/attributes.  There are multiple ways to approach the solution, but where I would start would be treating the array as an entity/table in your database and the elements of the array as rows in that entity/table.  The Decks CoreData entity should have a `card` attribute as one of the integer types to map back to your `astruct.card` enum property and a `status` attribute as a Boolean to map to your `astruct.status` property.

Note: if you take this approach the CoreData Boolean type is not compatible with the ObjC BOOL type.  CoreData works with the Boolean type as an NSNumber under the hood so your @NSManaged property would need to be an NSNumber, not Swift's Bool type.

Answer (score -1):

To-many relationships are typed to `NSSet` or `NSOrderedSet` according to how you configure the relationship in your managed object model.  Whatever type of object will be contained within those sets or ordered sets must also be a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and match the relationship as configured in the managed object model.

I like to create some generic functions for `NSSet` and `NSOrderedSet` that easily handle mapping them to an array of whatever value I want.

```
extension NSSet {
    func array<T>() -> [T] {
        var output = [T]()
        for obj in self.allObjects {
            if let t = obj as? T {
                output.append( t )
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}

extension NSOrderedSet {
    func array<T>() -> [T] {
        var output = [T]()
        for obj in self.array {
            if let t = obj as? T {
                output.append( t )
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

So in your case you'd have something like this:

```
// Model declarations
@objc class Model: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var decks: NSOrderedSet
}

@objc class Deck: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var status: NSNumber // For bool
    @NSManaged var cards: NSOrderedSet
}

@objc class Card: NSManagedObject {}

// Sample usage
if let model = loadModel() {
    let decks: [Deck] = model.decks.array()
    for deck in decks {
        let cards: [Card] = deck.cards.array()
    }
}
```

Comment: Deck is a struct. Card is an enum